# I want to set this icon like if the user wants to mark this chapter as it will read tapper this icon, so it will chancher to another icon

Tags: android, click, icons, android-recyclerview, cardview

I want to set this icon like if the user wants to mark this chapter as it will read tapper this icon, so it will chancher to another icon.

[image that described my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqHCh.jpg)

my files:
SeptCoursAdapter.java

```
public class SeptCoursAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeptCoursAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<ItemSeptCours> chapList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView chapitreTitle;
    public TextView  nbHeures;
    public ImageView pecLue;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        chapitreTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chapitre_title);
        nbHeures = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nb_heure);
        pecLue = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_lue);
    }
}


public SeptCoursAdapter(Context mContext, List<ItemSeptCours> chapList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.chapList = chapList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_item_7_cours, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

   ItemSeptCours itemSeptCours = chapList.get(position);
    holder.chapitreTitle.setText(itemSeptCours.getChapitreTitle());
    holder.nbHeures.setText(itemSeptCours.getNbHeures());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(itemSeptCours.getPecLue()).into(holder.pecLue);


    holder.pecLue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if(holder.pecLue.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
                holder.pecLue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chapList.size();
}
```

}

CoursSeptFragment.java

```
public class CoursSeptBaseFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ItemSeptCours> chapList;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cours_sept_base_fragment, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_sept);

    chapList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new SeptCoursAdapter(view.getContext(), chapList);


    if (recyclerView != null) {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    prepareChapitre();

    return view;
}


private void prepareChapitre() {

    int[] luePecTab = new int[]{
            R.drawable.ic_visibility_black_18dp_blue,
            R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_black_18dp_blue};

    ItemSeptCours a = new ItemSeptCours("Chap 1: Ordinateur et systèmes d'exploitation", "4 séances", luePecTab[0]);
    chapList.add(a);

    a = new ItemSeptCours("Chap 2: Exploitations de logiciels", "4 séances", luePecTab[0]);
    chapList.add(a);

    a = new ItemSeptCours("Chap 3: L'Internet : Le web", "4 séances", luePecTab[0]);
    chapList.add(a);

    a = new ItemSeptCours("Un mini projet", "6 séances", luePecTab[0]);
    chapList.add(a);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: to be sur i understant your want a button like favorite when you pressed it it fill itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are almost there. (assuming pecLue is your little eye image)

Pseudo code:

```
     holder.pecLue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //if(holder.pecLue.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
            //    holder.pecLue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

           if(conditionIfChapterIsMarked){
               holder.pecLue.setImageResource(R.drawable.pec_lue_icon_unmarked);
               //unmarkChapterLogic()
           }else{
               holder.pecLue.setImageResource(R.drawable.pec_lue_icon_marked); 
               //markChapterLogic()
           } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: t's very helpful, thinks freind